# Grub C Code in "set" output?

Tags: grub2, bash, root

i made an interesting discovery. When i run set as root the output displays some c code... it seems like some grub boot-loader code.. followed by some unreadable parts. That seems a bit ... wired to me. Hate to ask but ... is that a "Virus?" or at least unwanted Code?

Here a small snipped:

```
xspecs=([freeamp]="!*.@(mp3|og[ag]|pls|m3u)" [cdiff]="!*.@(dif?(f)|?(d)patch)?(.@([gx]z|bz2|lzma))" [bibtex]="!*.aux" [rgview]="*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)" [oowriter]="!*.@(sxw|stw|sxg|sgl|doc?([mx])|dot?([mx])|rtf|txt|htm|html|?(f)odt|ott|odm)" [chromium-browser]="!*.@(?([xX]|[sS])[hH][tT][mM]?([lL]))" [tex]="!*.@(?(la)tex|texi|dtx|ins|ltx|dbj)" [zathura]="!*.@(cb[rz7t]|djv?(u)|?(e)ps|pdf)" [netscape]="!*.@(?([xX]|[sS])[hH][tT][mM]?([lL]))" [acroread]="!*.[pf]df" [makeinfo]="!*.texi*" [kwrite]="*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)" [gview]="*.@(o|so|so.
```

... followed by c code:

```
_all_modules () 
{ 
    while read name; do
        name=${name%% *};
        printf "%s\n" "$name";
    done < <(pulseaudio --dump-modules 2> /dev/null)
}
__cards () 
{
```

For me that looks like it should not be there or am i wrong? Can i overwrite this var or will it destroy my grub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` simply shows functions defined in bash. What you see has nothing to do with GRUB or C. It is normal for these functions to be defined - they are used for things such as colored terminal output and tab completion.

Comment: Ahhh okey... good to know.. did not found that in any documentation... at least not by googeling something like "linux bash set command " thought the command should behave similar to windows set. Thought about grub because a lot of these functions begin with "__grub_dir"  Thanks.